# view not getting resolved spring boot web

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot web mvc. My view on RequestMapping("/") is not getting resolved. Below i have shared required code.
my controller class is

```
@Controller 
public class ExpenseSheetController {

@Autowired
private ExpenseSheetDao expenseSheetDao;

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("home");
    modelAndView.addObject("message","on home page");

    return modelAndView;
 }
}
```

pom.xml is as follows

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- my-sql connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have kept my view at **src/main/resources/templates** as **home.html**

Comment: What is your exception exactly?

Comment: Have you added any view resolver?

Comment: @Reno I am getting There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Comment: @Hareesh I have not added any view resolver

Comment: try to add view resolver and check it once

Comment: added view resolver but still not working.

Comment: I have created webapp/WEB-INF folder in src/main and added my view in that folder then it worked.